# What is the purpose of doing Sandyavandan ? To which Diety it is addressed ? Sun God ? What about people who cannot do it?

Tags: vedas

1)What is the purpose of doing Sandyavandan ?

2)To which Deity it is addressed ? Sun God ? What is Savitri Devata or Gayatri Mata ?

3)What if certain people like Sudras etc cannot do it ? What is the substitute prayer for them ?(I amnt asking verses to prove all Varnas can do Sandyavandan or Upanayana etc but only asking on a assumption that its only for 3 Varnas then what about rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandhya Vandana is done to help purify the mind.

**1)What is the purpose of doing Sandyavandan ?**

> Because of its supreme spiritual significance, the Gayatri-Mantra has
> been incorporated as the very core of a daily prayer-ritual known as
> Sandhya. Being in the nature of contemplation, the ritual is classed
> as Upasana or spiritual contemplation. .... As the Upasana is done at
> the conjunction-time (Sandhya), it is designated as the
> Sandhya-Upasana. It is also called Sandhya-Vandana (adoration or
> worhip), and often merely Sandhya. It can be practised by all without
> distinction of caste, color, creed or sex (cf:Sukla Yajur Veda XXVI.2)
>
> The sun above, the Giver of Life (Pusan) and Light (tejas) (CF. Isa
> Upanishad 16) is the great visible symbol of the Infinite Spiritual
> Sun, the source of all consciousness, the substratum of the entire
> Cosmic Universe, and the Inner Self (Antar-Atman) of all entities and
> beings in all the worlds of the Cosmic Universe. Man is a part and
> parcel of this Cosmic Universe, and within the 'Supreme Space'
> (Parama-Vyoman) or Sky of his psychic Heart (Hridaya-Akasah) (CF.
> Taittiriya Upanishad II.1.1; I.VI.1) is also indwelling that Spiritual
> Sun, reflected in the lake of his mind as the Jiva or Soul, which is
> the center of individual consciousness. The Sandhya-Upasana, with the
> visible sun in the sky as the symbol, is a sadhana (spiritual
> practice) to bring about the conjunction (Sandhi) of the individual
> Self with the Cosmic Self to realize the unity of both. **Sandhya,
> therefore, is a form of Yoga-Sadhana for the union of the individual
> with the Supreme Reality, and the Sandhya-ritual incorporates the
> elements or features of all the four main types of Yoga - Karma,
> Bhakti, Dhyana and Jnana.**
>
> **Sandhya is a specially devised efficient spiritual ritual for the
> realization of the Divinity of the Self (Atman). It is therefore not a
> Kamya Karma i.e. optional ritual to be performed occasionally for the
> attainment of worldly fulfilments. It is on the other hand a Nitya
> Karma or an obligatory daily ritual whose object is to bring about
> self-purification and attainment of Cosmic Reality.**

**OM, Gayatri and Sandhya by Swami Mukhyananda**

**2)To which Deity it is addressed ? Sun God ? What is Savitri Devata or Gayatri Mata?**

> It {the Gayatri Mantra] is also known as the Savitri-Mantra, **since it
> is addressed to the Divine Person in the Sun, Savita,** who is
> considered as the visible symbolic representation of the Supreme
> Divinity. For, He destroys darkness and promotes life, and He is also
> identified with the Inner Self of man. (Cf. Isa Upanishad 15-16)
>
> In course of time, just as the Om-kara was personified into Ganesa,
> **the Gayatri-Mantra also was personified into the Goddess Gayatri
> [Gayatri-Devi], as the presiding Deity of the Mantra, for purposes of
> personal upasana (saguna-upasana)**.

**OM, Gayatri and Sandhya by Swami Mukhyananda**

**3)What if certain people like Sudras etc cannot do it ? What is the substitute prayer for them ?(I amnt asking verses to prove all Varnas can do Sandyavandan or Upanayana etc but only asking on a assumption that its only for 3 Varnas then what about rest)**

I am not answering this question since Sandhya-Vandana should be opened to all.